# Errors when Validation function is in use with other function

Tags: python, function, validation

This is more of a continuation of my last question, I created a validation function for use with code I was given by a friend, here's the validation function which works fine(?):

```
def validation(goodNum,score):
goodNum = False
while goodNum == False:
    score = raw_input("Please enter a valid score between 1 and 10 ")
    try:
        score = int(score)
    except:
        continue 
    if score > 1 and score < 11:
        goodNum = True
    else:
        print "Invalid input"
return score
```

The issue I have is implementing this into the other function, which looks like this:

```
def scoreCalculator(finalists):
scores = []
sortedScores = []
for number in range(5):
    print ("Please enter a score for ", finalists[number])
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    for number in range(5):
        scores.append(validation(0,10))
        maxScore = scores[0]
        minScore = scores[0]
        for number in scores:
            if number > maxScore:
                maxScore = number
            elif number < minScore:
                minScore = number
                scores.remove[minScore]
                scores.remove[maxScore]
                sumScore = sum[scores]
                sortedScores.append(sumScore)
```

When attempting to run the program I receive the error:

```
line 57, in <module>
scoreCalculator(finalists)
line 44, in scoreCalculator
scores.remove[minScore]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

As a beginner to python I've never really seen this before, I've searched for a solution, but those I could find talked about indexes, which I don't have here(?), and things being called wrongly with a misuse of either () or [], but I'm not sure where I should correct if that is the case. Any tips?

Comment: The error is at line 44: scores.remove[minScore]. As said in the error message. You have to use () when calling function.

Comment: `()` is used to execute a function `[]` is to access the index of a collection object.

Comment: `scores.remove[minScore]` is the source of your problem. Using `[]` for indexing is equivalent to `scores.remove.__getitem__(minScore)`   but `remove` is a function. Just use `()` to make it function call.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I managed to resolve the issues I was having, yet I'm a little offput by the downvotes? Did I do something wrong by genuinely asking for advice?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Eolmar:

```
The error is at line 44: scores.remove[minScore]. As said in the error message. You have to use () when calling function.
```